# how to install foreign relay package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI everyone!
i am very new in ROS, and i am trying to use foreign_relay package to transfer topics between two computers(ROS_MASTER).
but in the documentation page i didn't see how to download or install the package.
can anyone help me please?

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200380/how-to-install-foreign-relay-package/) by [milorenus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21073/milorenus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you're "very new" to ROS, you likely don't need `foreign_relay`. ROS is a distributed system that supports topic sharing between computers out-of-the-box -- you simply need to use the `ROS_MASTER_URI` environment variable (see the [Running ROS across multiple machines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) tutorial).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3